# Xcode 13.1 - Unable to install Qt app on iPhone, "There was an internal API error."

Tags: ios, xcode, qt, xcode13

I'm building an app using Qt 5.12.5 using macOS Version 12.1 and Xcode 13.1 . The app builds fine, but when I try to install it to my iPhone 8 (iOS 15) it gives me an "Unable to install app" error. I've already tried rebooting my phone, rebooting XCode, deleting the xcodeproj file and generating it again, among other things but nothing seems to solve my problem.

I've also tried using the simulator, but it gives me the error "Failed to get FD to bundle executable at /Users/certtest/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D8E99574-E039-43D0-B8A4-29D1033F1647/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.dOfDJ8/extracted/myapplication.app/MyApplication" .

Down below is the stack trace of the iPhone error.

```
Unable to install "MyApplication"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your project settings and ensure that a valid product has been built.
User Info: {
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}
--
There was an internal API error.
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653081
User Info: {
    DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;
    MobileDeviceErrorCode = "(0xE8000067)";
    "com.apple.dtdevicekit.stacktrace" = (
    0   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x00000001194ee316 DTDKCreateNSErrorFromAMDErrorCode + 220
    1   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011952c84a __90-[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:]_block_invoke + 155
    2   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010dbd6ea4 DVTInvokeWithStrongOwnership + 71
    3   DTDeviceKitBase                     0x000000011952c594 -[DTDKMobileDeviceToken installApplicationBundleAtPath:withOptions:andError:withCallback:] + 1420
    4   IDEiOSSupportCore                   0x0000000115208b4e __118-[DVTiOSDevice(DVTiPhoneApplicationInstallation) processAppInstallSet:appUninstallSet:installOptions:completionBlock:]_block_invoke.292 + 3508
    5   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010dd0ac07 __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ + 7
    6   DVTFoundation                       0x000000010dd0c373 __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke + 931
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819ea5ad8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819ea6cc9 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819eaccee _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 696
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819ead7c8 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 366
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007ff819eb77e1 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 758
    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81a05a074 _pthread_wqthread + 326
    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007ff81a058ffb start_wqthread + 15
);
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone10,4";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.1 (19B74)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 5048;
    "operation_errorCode" = "-402653081";
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDEiPhoneRunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 5;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphoneos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_swiftVersion" = "5.5.1";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphoneos15.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "15.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphoneos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 12.1 (Build 21C5045a)
Xcode 13.1 (19466) (Build 13A1030d)
Timestamp: 2021-12-07T14:24:32-03:00
```